# Integers represented by powers of 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have observed something, and I'm hoping one of you are going to tell me, "oh, that's just the Slurbott sequence; Euler wrote a book on it in the 1700s" or something so I don't have to keep looking at it. :)

It appears that all integers $x >0$ (at least) can be uniquely represented by a pair of integers $(k, p)$ where $k\ge1$ and $p\ge0$ such that $x_k(p) = p2^k + a$, where $3a \equiv 1 \mod 2^{k-1}$. For instance, the first few frequencies are:
$x_1=2p$
$x_2=4p + 1$
$x_3=8p - 1$
$x_4=16p + 3$
$x_5=32p - 5$
$x_6=64p + 11$
etc.

$1 \rightarrow (2, 0)$
$2 \rightarrow (1, 1)$
$3 \rightarrow (4, 0)  $
$4 \rightarrow (1, 2)  $
$5 \rightarrow (2, 1)  $
$6 \rightarrow (1, 3)  $
$7 \rightarrow (3, 1)  $
$8 \rightarrow (1, 4)  $
$9 \rightarrow (2, 2)  $
$10 \rightarrow (1, 5) $
etc.

I think $3a$ can be congruent to $1 \mod 2^k$, but I prefer them in this sequence because it can be written as an alternating sum of the powers of $2$, which is easier.
$$a(k) = 
\begin{cases} 
\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} (-1)^i2^i & \text{if $k > 1$ } \\
0 & \text{if $ k = 1$}
\end{cases}$$

The point is that (I think) every positive integer (and maybe the rest, too, but I'm not looking at that) can be represented by exactly one pair.

I tried looking on the OEIS, but I don't even know the right search terms. I'm taking an online course on number theory to find out more about this and other questions, but I was watching a Numberphile video about the OEIS and thought I might get lucky here. Is this something known I can look up?

Thank you.

Comment: please clarify the question to include whether you want to if this series has a name or if you want a proof that it can represent all positive integers or both.

Comment: you can let $a(k) =\frac{(-2)^k+2}{6}$ for $k>0$ so that there is no piecewise function

Comment: @D S Yes (using the sum of a geometric series) otherwise said $3a(k)=1-(-2)^{k-1}$ which is direct relationship with the condition $3a \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 2^{k-1}$...

Comment: Sorry, layman here.... I do not seem to understand this completely. Do you mean that every integer $x$ can be written as $x=p2^k+a$? And $3a \equiv 1 \mod 2^{k-1}$ means that $3a-1$ has exactly $k-1$ factors 2?

Comment: @jonathan, on the use of OEIS. You open the site and type at least 4 elements of the sequence (more if you have more) and click on search or simply press enter. You will either get the full sequence or a sequence which shares elements with another sequence or it will let you known it's an unknown sequence.

Comment: If so (see my previous comment), then you could write $3a=1+(2q+1)2^{k-1}$, and for every $x$ that $3x=3p2^k+\left(1+(2q+1)2^{k-1}\right)$. Rewritten that is $3x-1=2^{k-1}(2(3p+q)+1)$. With $2(3p+q)+1$ being any odd number I see a unique solution for $k$, but never for $p$.

Comment: I doubt that OEIS will have anything enlightening. As I show in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4627559), for given $a$, any integer of form $x_{i-1}=mp+a$ ($m$ known, $p$ unknown) has form $2mp'+a$ or $2mp'+m+a$. You can choose whichever of these two you want as your $x_i$. Different choice-sequences give different number-sequences. For example, you could choose $x_3=8p+1$, ..., $x_i=2^i+1$. Then to find which form represents $n$, you find which power of 2 exactly divides $n+1$: $n$ has the form $x_i$ means that $2^{i-1}||n+1$.

Comment: Whoops. Make that $x_3=8p+3$, $x_4=16p+7$, ..., $x_i=2^i p+2^{i-1}-1$.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. Sorry about the delay responding; it's been a rough week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ be a known positive integer. (This corresponds to your $2^k$.) If $x$ has the form $mp+a$ (where $p$ is an integer), then $x$ has the form $mp+a$ either with $p$ even or with $p$ odd. If $p$ is even, $p$ has the form $2p'$, so $x=mp+a=2mp'+a$. If $p$ is odd, $p$ has the form $2p'+1$, so $x=mp+a=m(2p'+1)+a=2mp'+(m+a)$.

Now let's apply this idea to your forms $x_1$, $x_2$ etc..

Integers not represented by $x_1$ are odd, thus of the form $2p+1$, thus of either the form $x_2=4p+a_2$ or the form $x_2=4p+2^{2-1}+a_2$, where $a_2=1$.

Of these integers not represented by $x_1$, those not represented by $x_2$ have the form $4p+3$, or, equivalently, $4p-1$, thus of either the form $x_3=8p+a_3$ or the form $8p+2^{3-1}+a_3$, where $a_3=-1$.
And so on.

Comment: I had observed a similar thing, that $x_1$ covers evens, $x_2$ covers $1 \mod 4$, out of the remaining $3 \mod 4 = 3,7\mod8$, $x_3$ covers $7 \mod 8$, out of the remaining $3 \mod 8 = 3,11 \mod 16$, $x_4$ covers $3 \mod 16$ and so on, but is there a rigorous proof that if $x_n$ does not cover $z \mod 2^n = z,z+2^n \mod 2^{n+1}$, then $x_{n+1}$ covers at least one of $z$ or $z+2^n$ modulo $2^{n+1}$?