# Word for something like a covering system but with infinite residue classes?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In this post([Integers represented by powers of 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627410/integers-represented-by-powers-of-2)), I describe what I now know is similar to a covering system, where any integer can be represented by

$$\{ \frac{(-1)^k(2^{k-1}) + 1}{3} \pmod{2^k} : \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

That is, all integers fall into the residue classes

$$ \{ 0 \pmod{2}, 1 \pmod{4}, -1 \pmod{8}, 3 \pmod{16}, -5 \pmod{32}, ... \}$$

Is there a word for a covering-system-like thing that doesn't have a finite number of residue classes, but an infinite number of residue classes that are, I don't know the word, but possibly "constructible"? The definition in Wikipedia for "Covering System" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) specifically mentions "finitely many residue classes".

Thank you.

Comment: I imagine "infinite covering system" would work just fine. As with any definition, we'd include the details for the reader once and choose words that will evoke the right intuitions.